# plot word cloud errors

Tags: r, word-cloud

I was trying to plot a word cloud in R. My code is as below. The wordcloud can be plotted but the font size of all words are equally the same. It does not list the words with higher frequency in the front and show in bigger font sizes. Can anybody point what mistakes I made? Thank you!

```
install.packages('tm')
library(tm)

reviews <- read.csv('keywords_2.csv',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
review_text <- paste(reviews$customer_search_term
                     , collapse =" ")
review_source<-VectorSource(review_text)
corpus<-Corpus(review_source)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

dtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm2<-as.matrix(dtm)

install.packages('wordcloud')
library(wordcloud)
frequency<- colSums(dtm2)
str(frequency)
words<-names(frequency)
wordcloud(words,scale=c(1,.0005), min.freq = 3,random.order = FALSE, rot.per = .15)
```

Comment: your example is not reproducible. what's the result of `words`? if returned by `names` is probably just a `character` ?! have you tried `wordcloud(frequency, ...)` instead?

Comment: thank you @Vincent Bonhomme, i figured it out that names() is not needed. I can just do wordcloud(corpus,....) then, they will be all good.